# Mongo 2.4.1 upgrade causing Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\MongoDB\Util\InvalidArgumentException' not found

Tags: mongodb, symfony, boost, php-mongodb

I had everything working and I upgraded my mac ports on my mac to get the latest packages. It installed Mongo 2.4.1 and I also got boost @1.53.0_1+no_single+no_static+python27. Now when I try interfacing using the same code in my Symfony 2 application, I get :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\MongoDB\Util\InvalidArgumentException' not found in /Users/saudfaisal/Sites/dailytamatar.com/vendor/doctrine/mongodb/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Util/ReadPreference.php on line 63
```

my composer.json looks like the following:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "*",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev"
    },  "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

I know in the past there was an issue with boost and one had to roll back to boost @1.49.0_0 however that did not work this time.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in version 1.0.2 of the `doctrine/mongodb` package, which was released a few months ago. The actual commit is [b317c8e](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/commit/b317c8e30e9510703fa3d2c2942c4e466d521b4a#lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Util/ReadPreference.php) if you'd like to confirm.

I would suggest explicitly requiring `doctrine/mongodb-odm` and possibly `doctrine/mongodb` in your `composer.json` file, instead of rely on the bundle's internal dependency. Additionally, it's likely that your `composer.lock` file is pointing to an outdated release of `doctrine/mongodb` that still satisfies the version requirement for ODM. In that case, you'll want to upgrade your dependencies (via `composer upgrade`), which should also upgrade your lock file and the version/commit points therein.